# PDF file in slack

Tags: java, file, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm trying to add file to slack message in my interactive app using List in java
I have PDF file in azure storage and link to the file that look like that https://azure.blob.core.windows.net/path/file.pdf
I also have the file in File object java.io.File;

how can I add it to the list probably using the FileBlock object?

I tried to add to the asBlocks method FileBlock but I couldn't find a way to make it work or give it my URL I get the invalid block error